# Is there a way to sample on a 'type' column, whilst keeping all ID's within that type in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I'm splitting a dataframe into two; one to get the average over a period of time, and the other to use that average on. The dataframe looks similar to the following:

```
ID    Type    Num. Hours     Month

2     black       10           Jan

2     black       12           Feb

2     black       15           March

3     red         7            Jan

3     red         10           Feb
```

The ID's each have 24 rows, spanning over 2 years. Different ID's can have the same Type or different Type. 
I'd like the two split dataframes to have the same amount of different Type's in, whilst keeping all 24 of the ID's together for each unique ID.

I've tried grouping by Type and ID, together and separately, but it seems to give me only a fraction of the ID's instead of keeping them together

`df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Type'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5))`

or

`df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5))`

and afterwards of course I would use than index to get the second split dataframe from the original.

Neither have worked the way I require.

For the output, it should be two dataframes, which should not share any ID's and have an equal amount of different Types.

So using something similar to the above, I would hopefully output a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
ID    Type    Num. Hours     Month

2     black       10           Jan

2     black       12           Feb

2     black       15           March

5     yellow       17           Jan

5     yellow       21           Feb
```

Using that table would allow me to index on the original dataframe and give me a second table which outputs something similar to the following:

```
ID    Type    Num. Hours     Month

4     black       10           Jan

4     black       12           Feb

4     black       15           March

6     yellow      22            Jan

6     yellow      27            Feb
```

Comment: You've given an example of data. Can you also provide example of desired output?

Comment: I can't write out the full output as it might not be clear, but I've written out the output if that helps!

Comment: So you mean that every `ID` in df1 should only occur in df1, and every `ID` in df2 should only occur in df2?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And if the original df has 10 ID's with the same type, df1 and df2 should have 5 different ID's each with that type

Comment: So am I correct that there is no reason to group on `Type`, as a row with a certain `ID` always has to be with his other `ID`-buddies?
And does every `ID` has the same number of rows, and if not is the problem about splitting the `ID`'s so that both groups are exactly the same size?

Comment: Yes that does make sense actually

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample takes a fraction but does not split the dataframe in two. Having obtained half of the samples, taking the other half is simple!

I am assuming your original line works as you want it to work for the first dataframe

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5))
df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

**Update**

Based on comments; to randomly divide your `ID`'s over two dataframes you can use the following:

```
import random

unique_ids = df.ID.unique()
random.shuffle(unique_ids)
id_set_1 = unique_ids[: len(unique_ids) // 2]  # take first half of list

df1 = df[df.ID.isin(id_set_1)]
df2 = df[~df.ID.isin(id_set_2)]
```

**Beware that this could lead to two dataframes with very different sizes, depending on the number of types per ID!**

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear, getting the second part is fine. I'm having trouble ending up with a dataframe which houses a ratio of 0.5 for Type, but keeps all ID's grouped.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your output, I feel like I'm close to this:
`For the output, it should be two dataframes, which should not share any ID's and have an equal amount of different Types.`

Comment: What do you mean with grouped / keeping together? You can just group these dataframes again / add a new column mark a new column with 'df1' / 'df'2' and then group this df?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. I've added an example of a desired output if that helps

Comment: added a small warning. Good luck data sciencing!